# Remove Common Factor from the expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

In this problem, I have  to remove the common factor from both the expression(9+10+5), (4+2+178)
the first part of the expression is (9+10+5) .this evaluates to 24. the second part of the expression is (4+2+178) this evaluates 184 removing all common factors of 24 and 184 results in 3/23.

I am stuck after getting 24 and 184 anyone knows the logic please help !!

```
def solution(expression):
    left_sum=0
    right_sum=0
    for i in range(len(expression)):
        if (expression[i]=='/'):
            first=expression[:i]
            second= expression[i+1:]
    left = eval(first)
    # print(left)
    right= eval(second) 
    # print(right)
    left_add=[]
    right_add=[]
    i=1
    for i in range(1,min(left,right)):
        if(left%i==0 and right %i==0):
            left= left//i
            right= right//i
            # print(i)
            # print(right)
            
       
solution("(9+10+5)/(4+2+178)")
```

Comment: Did you make *any* effort at finding an algorithm to compute common factors of 2 numbers?

Comment: I think you'd want to look into `math.gcd` (Greatest common divisor). And so `math.gcd(24, 184)` returns 8, `24/8 = 3`, `184/8 = 23`.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily find the common factor by use a function like:

```
def commonfactor(a,b): 
if(b==0): 
    return a 
else: 
    return commonfactor(b,a%b) 
print(commonfactor(24,184))
```

do after ending your calculations you can find the common factor and then divide both 24,184 by that